# How to make Three.js Extrude Geometry use Local UV coordinates for texturing rather than using World Coordinates

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, texturing, uv-mapping

I kept running into an issue while attempting to apply textures to my objects in three.js. Whenever I tried to texture an extruded geometry the texture just didn't show up. After giving up for a while then coming back and digging some more I found that ExtrudedGeometry.js uses world coordinates when applying a texture.

I would like to change this to local coordinates so that my texture wraps correctly. I've been looking for a while but I can't seem to find anything related to this topic. Here are the discussions that helped me get this far and a UV generator include.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1396

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1824

```
BoundingUVGenerator = {
generateTopUV: function( geometry, extrudedShape, extrudeOptions, indexA, indexB, indexC) {
    var ax = geometry.vertices[ indexA ].x,
        ay = geometry.vertices[ indexA ].y,

        bx = geometry.vertices[ indexB ].x,
        by = geometry.vertices[ indexB ].y,

        cx = geometry.vertices[ indexC ].x,
        cy = geometry.vertices[ indexC ].y,

        bb = extrudedShape.getBoundingBox(),
        bbx = (bb.maxX - bb.minX),
        bby = (bb.maxY - bb.minY)

    return [
        new THREE.UV( ( ax - bb.minX ) / bbx, 1 - ( ay - bb.minY ) / bby ),
        new THREE.UV( ( bx - bb.minX ) / bbx, 1 - ( by - bb.minY ) / bby ),
        new THREE.UV( ( cx - bb.minX ) / bbx, 1 - ( cy - bb.minY ) / bby )
    ];
},

generateBottomUV: function( geometry, extrudedShape, extrudeOptions, indexA, indexB, indexC) {
    return this.generateTopUV( geometry, extrudedShape, extrudeOptions, indexA, indexB, indexC );
},

generateSideWallUV: function( geometry, extrudedShape, wallContour, extrudeOptions,
                              indexA, indexB, indexC, indexD, stepIndex, stepsLength,
                              contourIndex1, contourIndex2 ) {
    var ax = geometry.vertices[ indexA ].x,
        ay = geometry.vertices[ indexA ].y,
        az = geometry.vertices[ indexA ].z,

        bx = geometry.vertices[ indexB ].x,
        by = geometry.vertices[ indexB ].y,
        bz = geometry.vertices[ indexB ].z,

        cx = geometry.vertices[ indexC ].x,
        cy = geometry.vertices[ indexC ].y,
        cz = geometry.vertices[ indexC ].z,

        dx = geometry.vertices[ indexD ].x,
        dy = geometry.vertices[ indexD ].y,
        dz = geometry.vertices[ indexD ].z;

    var amt = extrudeOptions.amount,
        bb = extrudedShape.getBoundingBox(),
        bbx = bb.maxX - bb.minX,
        bby = bb.maxY - bb.minY;

    if ( Math.abs( ay - by ) < 0.01 ) {
        return [
            new THREE.UV( ax / bbx, az / amt),
            new THREE.UV( bx / bbx, bz / amt),
            new THREE.UV( cx / bbx, cz / amt),
            new THREE.UV( dx / bbx, dz / amt)
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            new THREE.UV( ay / bby, az / amt ),
            new THREE.UV( by / bby, bz / amt ),
            new THREE.UV( cy / bby, cz / amt ),
            new THREE.UV( dy / bby, dz / amt )
        ];
    }
}};
```

I could really use some help with this. It's an issue I've been dealing with for a while and yet I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Did you come to any conclusions about this?

Comment: I found some round about ways to deal with the issue. It seemed that for cylindrical extruded objects the texture wrapping had been repeated 100 times over (similar to world-coordinates vs local coordinates in animation). I repeated it negatively by 100 and this seemed to fix it. I also had to edit the applied texture so that it was cut into four quadrants and the center of the image was moved to each corner (I rotated each quadrant, if that makes any sense). That seemed to work but the parts of my geometry that were not extruded did not receive a texture due to the -100 wrapping.